# Agglomerative Clustring to Quantize colors in Image. Image array analysis

Tags: image, scipy, cluster-computing, python-imaging-library

I want to do Agglomerative Clustering. I want to group similar pixels based on their distance difference and also want to keep the original track of pixel. when group I want a denderogram representation.
here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
import numpy
from numpy.random import rand
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("/home/Desktop/Ladybug.jpg")
img1 = img.convert(mode  ='RGB')
X = numpy.asarray(img1)
y = pdist(X)
z=linkage(y)
dendrogram(z)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this error

```
raise ValueError('A 2-dimensional array must be passed.');
ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.
```

the problem is 3 dimensional array that has to converted in 2-d format
please guide.

Comment: You probably want `img.convert(mode='L')` if you want a 2d grayscale array.

Comment: This works for me: `dendrogram(linkage(pdist(img.convert('L'))))`

Comment: Can we highlight the nodes in dendrogram and get values at each node. And how we change the color of dendrogram branches with the original image color. Likewise at the bottom of dendrogram we have our original image, and as we moves up in the tree we reduce the colors.

Comment: I believe that merits a separate question, with an image and some better explanation.  As it stands, your question is asking about a simple bug in conversion from a color image to b&w.